# ASP .NET MVC - How to send html from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have text formated with HTML saved in database.
Now what I want to do is to get that text and send it view, with all html formating. But all I get is:
    & lt; p & gt;

Which is no exactly what I want. Any ideas how to get

Answer (score 9):

Don't HTML encode in the view:

Razor:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.SomeHtmlStringComingFromTheDatabase)
```

WebForms:

```
<%= Model.SomeHtmlStringComingFromTheDatabase %>
```

Remark: by doing this you acknowledge that you fully understand the consequences of [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) that your application becomes vulnerable to and that you do the necessary to sanitize this HTML if it comes from user input.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using Html.Raw() in your view.